# ssl false with port 465 does not throw exception for server smtp.gmail.com

Tags: java, email, smtp, gmail, jakarta-mail

I am trying to connect to my gmail account using com.sun.mail ..... Mail api.
I am using mail api version 1.4.2 - mail_1.4.2.jar
Now I am trying to connect with following details as :

```
username : username@gmail.com
password : some password (correct password)
host : smtp.gmail.com
port : 465
SSL : false
```

But when I try to execute `Transport.connect(host,port,username,password)`, it just hangs -- no error return, no exception. Please help me out as if SSL is no then it should prompt me some error.

I am able to connect with SSl as true and rest of the configurations are same as above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SSMTP is typically on port 465.

SMTP is typically on port 25.

Try again, but use `port : 25`. Google might enforce TLS/SSL on 465.

Comment: throwing error with port 25: com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPSendFailedException: 530 5.7.0 Must issue a STARTTLS command first. wf3sm4567638icb.9

Comment: Aha! Looks like Google _requires_ SSL/TLS. Unencrypted doesn't look like an option.

Comment: what I need is : if user provide ssl as false with port 465, then we should prompt him/her for wrong ssl. changing port to 25 is not my solution.

Comment: [Google requires SSL or TLS for SMTP](http://mail.google.com/support/bin/answer.py?answer=13287). So if your program is specifically for gmail, then hard-code `SSL: true`. If your program is for use with any SMTP server, then feel free to fall back to unencrypted port 25 if 465 is closed or you cannot negotiate a connection.

Comment: Using my java desktop application, user can use any SMTP server. So you are saying we need to hard-code port: 25 with SSL : false.. right?

Comment: Out of curiosity, why do you want to forbid using SSL/TLS?

Comment: My client configures SMTP profile for sending reports on his/her mail account. We ask our client to provide : server, port, from, to, password and ssl (true/false) for configure SMTP profile. All are mandatory part for client. Now if user set SSL - false with Port - 465 then our code must prompt client check your ssl as it must be - true for port 465. That's not happening. Application is getting stuck while connecting with wrong ssl-port connection.

Comment: We need solution for this issue. We do not want hard-code any thing. but we need proper message prompting if user provided wrong port and ssl combination. please suggest if we are doing some thing wrong..

Comment: Thanks for the explanation; does [`Transport.connect()`](http://javamail.kenai.com/nonav/javadocs/javax/mail/Service.html#connect(java.lang.String,%20int,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)) throw an Exception? Or does it return `false` or something similar when it fails?

Comment: No.. It get stuck on that line of code and never returns control back to the next line for execution. It looks program get terminate.

Comment: Wow. Not returning an error or throwing an exception when SSL/TLS cannot be negotiated sounds awful. :( I'm sorry most of this discussion was completely irrelevant -- but I've edited your post to include what I think would help someone else understand the problem better.

Comment: Can you start your connection in a new thread, and kill the thread after 15 to 20 seconds if the connection isn't successfully established? You could set a thread-local-storage flag to true immediately after the `connect()` call, and check that flag from the main thread after 15 or 20 seconds. If it is still false, kill the thread, and try without SSL. If it is true, then the connection was successful, and you can continue.